# Ubuntu: FTP works in Filezilla but not with ftp program

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I'm using Ubuntu, and FTP works in Filezilla, but when I try to use the `ftp` program, I could log in but the file transfers are often stalled (and fail with timeout), except sometimes when the file is very small.

I heard something about "passive" and "active" transfer but I'm not sure if it could make a difference.

What is the likely setting that would allow the `ftp` program to work?  Or else why would Filezilla work but not `ftp`?

Comment: I don't think there is an obvious reason for the `ftp` command to fail when Filezilla works; but it would be very interesting to record both sessions with `tcpdump`  and comparing them. Meanwhile, I would guess that using passive transfer is widely the default. Does using the `-p`  flag help?

Comment: Have you tried `ncftp` command?

Answer (score 0):

filezilla authomaticaly switches p/a mode, but using ftp you sould explicitly set the mode. Here is good explanation of a/p difference on stackpverflow [What is the difference between active and passive FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp)